# upgrade UIWebView to WKWebView in Cordova

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins, wkwebview, xcode14

in my Cordova have iOS platform and use UIWebView but this is becoming obsolete and must upgrade to WKWebView for use this add WKWebView plugin with this script
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`
but my Cordova iOS version is 4.3.4 and must be update to 5.1.1 or newer
so update to Cordova iOS 6.0.0 but after build project not convert my code where use UIWebView to WKWebView and have error
`'Cordova/CDVURLProtocol.h' file not found`
can help me for this problem
how to use WKWebView in my project
I use Xcode version 14

I try install plugin and build project so It should be implemented according to the training instructions and without the need to change anything else

use this [tutorials](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cordova iOS 6+, you do not need `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` anymore as WKWebView is the default. The plugin is deprecated (and CDVWKWebViewEngine, CordovaWebViewEngine and WKWebViewOnly features/preferences are obsolete).
See https://cordova.apache.org/2021/02/07/deprecate-wkwebview-engine.html and https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html

Comment: before use WKWebView use UIWebView and use cordova-plugin-crypto-file for encode request but now can't use this and delete plugin now not send request to service how fixed in WKWebView
and how to encrypt url in WKWebVeiw

Comment: That's another whole question, close this one and ask these questions in a new thread